# Evaluate this finite summation

Tags: combinatorics

$$
\sum_{k_1=0}^{N-1}\frac{\binom{N-1}{k_1}(\beta -2)^{N-1-k_1}}{1+k_1+\alpha(N-1-k_1)}
$$

where  $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha >1$  (1.3 say), $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta >2 $, and N is a finite natural number

Comment: All i could do was find an upper bound for the summation as 
$(\beta - 1)^{N-1}$

Comment: Have you tried using Gosper's algorithm or (since it has compact support) Zeilberger's algorithm?

Comment: @PeterTaylor
Had not heard of the algorithms that you have mentioned. Will read up on them and give them a try.Thanks

Comment: WolframAlpha's [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28%28binomial%28n-1,k%29*%28b-2%29%5E%28n-1-k%29%29/%281%2bk%2ba*%28n-1-k%29%29,k=0..n-1%29) in hypergeometric form. ![result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fEO3B.gif)

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k_1=0}^{N-1}\frac{\binom{N-1}{k_1}(\beta -2)^{N-1-k_1}}{1+k_1+\alpha(N-1-k_1)}< \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k_1=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}{k_1}(\beta -2)^{N-1-k_1}$ since $\alpha>1$.

Now, $\sum_{k_1=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}{k_1}(\beta -2)^{N-1-k_1}=(\beta-1)^{N-1}$ by binomial theorem. Hence, we have

$\displaystyle\sum_{k_1=0}^{N-1}\frac{\binom{N-1}{k_1}(\beta -2)^{N-1-k_1}}{1+k_1+\alpha(N-1-k_1)}< \frac{(\beta-1)^{N-1}}{N}.$

Comment: Thanks for getting a tighter bound

Comment: Likewise, this sum is $\gt(\beta-1)^{N-1}/(1+\alpha(N-1))$.